# Send POST request with body in R

Tags: r, post, httr

Here I need to send POST request where I body: `{"pipelineName":"some_pipeline"}` and `Content-Type:application/json`. Here is what I did

```
library(httr)

res = POST("https://some_url",
             body = list(pipelineName ="some_pipeline"),
             add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json")))
```

it came back with status 400. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
res <- POST("https://some_url", body = list(pipelineName ="some_pipeline"), encode = "json")
```